# file_get_contents breaks some characters

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm quite fresh to all of this, but I've partially managed to do what I wanted. But the file_get_contents doesn't show characters properly.

The code I'm using is:

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://pay.ebillett.no/eb_show.php?p_id=1203');
$content = str_replace('</title>','</title><base href="https://pay.ebillett.no/" />', $content);
echo $content;
```

My WordPress page is encoded in UTF-8, and the page I'm attempting to include into my page is encoded in ISO-8859-1. How can I convert the ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8?

Comment: are you sending an `content-encoding` header?

Comment: @pc-shooter, that was not supposed to be there. Fixed my post.

Comment: @Valerij, probably not as I don't know what that is.

Comment: see answer below. This is a simple fix.

Comment: @user3615574 Please don't edit answers into questions. Post it as a new answer (and you can mark it as "accepted" after 3 days).

Comment: transcoding is done using `iconv()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the corrosponding meta `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">` to your page that displays the contents.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('https://pay.ebillett.no/eb_show.php?p_id=1203');
$content = str_replace('</title>','</title><base href="https://pay.ebillett.no/" />', $content);
echo $content;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can do it like this without the html wrap also:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('https://pay.ebillett.no/eb_show.php?p_id=1203');
$content = str_replace('</title>','</title><base href="https://pay.ebillett.no/" />', $content);
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">';
echo $content;

?>
```

Comment: Neither seems to work. Thing is that I'm running a WordPress site, everywhere else characters show fine, just not in this specific area where I've included an external page.

http://nynorskenshus.no/speleliste/

Comment: @user3615574 - try setting the `charset` of your wordpress template to `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: I added <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> to the header of the theme, but it didn't help anything.

Comment: The meta tags are now:
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Alright, I've gotten word from the "eBillett"-people that their site is encoded in ISO-8859-1, and mine in UTF-8. Is there a way to simply convert the content to UTF-8?